# IIS 7.5 Native Module Not Loading

Tags: c++, iis, native

I am trying to develop a native (CPP) IIS 7.5 module that will handle a specific type of request using visual studio 2010 and I am having a heck of a time. The library builds correctly however it appears IIS is never calling RegisterModule.

Things I have verified:

- The module is listed in globalModules and modules.
- The library looks all good from dependency walker and has no missing dependencies.
- Built the library as a Win32 release DLL.
- Verified the definition file is correct.
- I build the [IIS7NativeModule](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/develop-a-native-cc-module-for-iis) provided by Microsoft and it also gets the same errors.

The error generated by IIS is as follows:

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "URLModule" has a bad module "IIS7NativeModule" in its module list
```

My end goal is to provide a URL such as "/track?code=testing123" and respond either with an error message or redirect the user to a specific URL based on the GET code.

Any thoughts / advice, etc?

Thanks!

Nate